# Laptop dies and does not complete boot process if not on AC, yet battery is fine

Tags: linux, laptop, linux-mint, battery, power

My laptop, after a hard 6 years of use, is finally showing signs of electrical wear and tear through a myriad of strange issues, this being one of the least severe of them.

I've experienced recently (and consistently) the issue that my laptop will cut out within about a second of being unplugged from an outlet. The strange thing about my issue is that it isn't simply a dead battery refusing to hold charge, as it (a) does not complain in sleep mode; (b) will turn on, but at times will not show bios splash and at other times will get past grub and die upon OS initialization; (c) delays before dying when unplugged while powered by about the same time as it would delay before showing unplugged before the issue presented itself; and (d) relays accurate ACPI information that shows nothing wrong (as far as I can tell). If not for (a) and (d), I could have found it reasonable to consider it a bad connection either to the battery or on the motherboard, the former of which I attempted to test by reinserting the battery several times.

The data to back up (d) is:

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state
present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          charging
present rate:            843 mA
remaining capacity:      3546 mAh
present voltage:         12514 mV

$ cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/info
present:                 yes
design capacity:         4400 mAh
last full capacity:      3782 mAh
battery technology:      rechargeable
design voltage:          11100 mV
design capacity warning: 0 mAh
design capacity low:     0 mAh
cycle count:          0
capacity granularity 1:  1 mAh
capacity granularity 2:  1 mAh
model number:            MS-1058

serial number:           

battery type:            LION

OEM info:                MSI Corp.

$ acpi -V
Battery 0: Full, 100%
Battery 0: design capacity 4400 mAh, last full capacity 3782 mAh = 85%
[...]
```

As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with the battery itself. I bought it less than a year ago from Amazon to replace the previous battery that had very obviously lost the ability to hold charge.

If the laptop is unplugged while sleeping (with the sleep indicator blinking), it will drain power from the battery as it normally would while on if this issue was not present and has no issues with being unplugged, leading me to believe that it may be a kernel or other software issue (though I don't recall making any noteworthy changes in the past few days). Once returned to AC after draining power in sleep, it will recharge the battery as normal.

EDIT: Not sure if this information is entirely useful, but the laptop is an MSI A6000 running Linux Mint 12.

Comment: I had a UPS here that the battery passed it's self check.  If called upon for real it failed, though.  Upon battery replacement I found several swollen cells and it behaved properly after that.  It seems like the battery could deliver the load for a few seconds but then the output dropped.

Comment: Oh wow, that is interesting and possible. But was your UPS always experiencing that? My battery will drain entirely without failure if left sleeping for a while and displays capacity accurately.

Comment: What happened with my UPS was the battery getting old.  I have no idea of the total capacity, my system has never been called upon to provide more than a couple of minutes of power.